# What happens to `this` once you convert a component to use React Hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I was wondering how you can get a component to reference itself once it becomes a hook, previously when it was a class-based component, we had the `this` keyword which would be a reference to itself. But, what is the equivalent when using hooks?

E.g.

In my old code, I had a function which took `this` (where `this` is of type `React.Component`) as a parameter.

```
componentDidMount() {
  doSomething(this);
}
```

I know how to convert the lifecycle method to its hook equivalent, but what would I replace `this` with?

Comment: Can you provide sample code on what you are trying to achieve. Chances are high you might not have to use `this` altogether, as Functional components are totally different from class Components

Comment: Tell us what you don't think you have access to, and I'll be happy to show you the equivalent hook using functional component.

Comment: Hey, just updated my question for more clarity, hope this makes more sense now.

Comment: This is less about react and more about a `class` vs a `function` in javascript.  The keyword `this` is only relevant when talking about an object, or the instance of a class, which is what React class components create.  A functional component is different, so the meaning of `this` really doesn't apply the same way.

Comment: What are you trying to do with your `doSomething` function?  I'm sure you can write things differently when working with a functional component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "equivalent" here is just access to the scope of your local variables.

Instead of:

```
class ClassComp {
  constructor() {
    this.state.foo = 'data'
  }
  render() {
    return <div>{this.state.foo}{this.props.bar}</div>
  }
}
```

You simply have:

```
function FuncComp({bar}) {
  const [foo, setFoo] = useState('data')
  return <div>{foo}{bar}</div>
}
```

When using hooks in a functional component, everything that matters about *that component* is a local variable in your function.

You don't need `this` because you're in it, and you already have access to everything around you.

---

> what if I had a function which took this as a parameter previously which was called in componentDidMount, how would I reference the entire functional component?

Let's say this used to be that function:

```
function funcThatTakesThis(instance) {
  return `${instance.state.foo}${instance.props.bar}`
}
```

Instead, you just move that function into your render function so it can access the local variables too:

```
function FuncComp({bar}) {
  const [foo, setFoo] = useState('data')

  function funcThatUsedToTakeThis() {
    return `${foo}${bar}`
  }

  return <div>{funcThatUsedToTakeThis()}</div>
}
```

Or you keep it external but pass in everything that function needs:

```
function funcThatUsedToTakeThis(foo, bar) {
  return `${foo}${bar}`
}

function FuncComp({bar}) {
  const [foo, setFoo] = useState('data')
  return <div>{funcThatUsedToTakeThis(foo, bar)}</div>
}
```

Comment: Okay, I think my question was worded poorly, what if I had a function which took `this` as a parameter previously which was called in componentDidMount, how would I reference the entire functional component?

Comment: A reference to a whole functional component like that wouldn't do you any good, since you would be able to access any of the data of function it defines. So either move that function into your functional component, so it also has access to all your local variables. Or you move outside and pass in each piece of data your function needs indivudually.

Comment: Perfect, thank you for your answer, I'd give you an upvote, but I don't have enough points haha